What directory does Steinberg's VST3 plugin generator expect?
I am trying to make a new plugin using the VST Project Generator that is bundled with the Steinberg VST3 SDK.  It requires the path to the SDK, but it rejects the path with the message "The selected folder does not look like the root folder of the VST SDK."  What path is the program expecting?
I have downloaded the Steinberg VST3 SDK, generated build files with Cmake, and then built all with visual studio.  It seems to be working correctly, as the built demo VST3 plugins work in my DAW.  The VST3 Project Generator still rejects the SDK path.  I have tried inputting the path to several subfolders instead, renaming the root folder, rebuilding all files, and redownloading the SDK from within the app, but I still get the same error message.

I solved the issue.  Build files generated by Cmake need to be placed in a subfolder of the vst3sdk folder that you downloaded from Steinberg.  Only after these build files are created, the VST3 project generator will recognize vst3sdk as the sdk root directory.
